# Spring scheduler not launch as scheduled

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks

I'm using to scheduler feature of Spring to run a Spring batch jobLauncher every 15 seconds. This JobLauchner then spawn about 200 spring batch job. 
When I run in my local machine, with job spawn is configured to 10 batch jobs, instead of 200. The scheduler run smoothly, it run every 15 seconds exactly, create 10 jobs each time.

However, when I run in server, scheduler does not work as expected, it doesn't run every 15 seconds, but may be 3 minutes or 10 minutes, not fix, it doesn't throw exception at all. Of course, the jobLauncher still spawns 200 jobs as expected every it's launched by scheduler. Only that scheduler doesn't run every 15 seconds, so the total launched batch jobs in every minutes is not expected to consume huge data.

I guess that there's not enough RAM in server, so scheduler can't run more threads, but not sure.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = 15000)
    public void launchBatchJobs( ) {

        JobParameters parameter = new JobParameters(mapJob);
        try {
            JobExecution jobExcution = jobLauncher.run(dataPartitionJob, parameter);
        } 
        catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobRestartException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            logger.error("error happens");
        }   
     }
```

Comment: Maybe try @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000), as according to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks? fixedRateString is for parametized expressions, which yours is not

Comment: Can also try @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000, initialDelay = 5) (or whatever initialDelay you want)

Comment: According to your code, a single job (`dataPartitionJob`) is run every 15s and not 10 jobs, so the method name `launchBatchJobs` should be in singular. There are two task executors involved in your case: One that is responsible for launching tasks scheduled with `@Scheduled`, and another one configured on the `jobLauncher` used to launch batch jobs (a `SyncTaskExecutor` by default). Can you share the config of each executor?